# How do I type "X feet Y inches" so that Spotlight suggests unit conversions?

Tags: ios, spotlight

I use the metric system, and when I want to convert imperial distance units of feet and inches, e.g. "5 feet 6 inches", I try to type it into Spotlight in iOS 15.5.

If I use the format `5'` I get a suggestion, but I can't figure out how to combine feet *and* inches. `5'6"` doesn't work. Neither does spelling out "feet" and "inches", nor combining the with a plus sign, nor `5'6 feet`...

Is there a format that Spotlight recognizes?

Comment: 5'6" works for me on iOS 15.5. I'm wondering if it might be dependent on the system language or region, I run my phone in English (UK) with Sweden as the region. Do you use English as well or another language?

Comment: @Lizzan Thanks for the info. Swedish/Swedish. I know the literal unit names are localized (hence my focus on format) and they work in isolation, but not combined. Still the `'` and `"` also work in isolation making it very strange if it's a localization issue.

Comment: Also it *should* be the region settings that determine which number and unit formatters are used...

Comment: Sure, it *should*, but in this case it might be language dependent anyway. Or simply a bug.